# Dart package to access MariaDb/Mysql with pool connection

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, mariadb, backend

I would like an indication for a mysql/mariadb connection package with connection pooling. I want to use it with Dart on the backend.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/mysql1 appears in a quick search. Does it do what you want? Its changelog suggests it has connection pooling.

Comment: Just for reference to other readers, despite the changelo, the package doesn't support connections pool (at the time of writing this). That changelog originates from the SQLJockey driver (probably some copy&Paste), so something changed in the meantime and pools are not supported anymore